# Scala promise does not work if I encapsulate it in a commodity function

Tags: scala, spray

I have this code that I use in a spray handler

```
 get {

        def callService = {
          val p = Promise[Option[DocumentRef]]
          val fut = p.future
          archiveService.getByHash(ZeroHash, {
            result => p success result
          })
          fut
        }


        onComplete(OnCompleteFutureMagnet(callService)){
          case Success(docRef) => {


            val doc = docRef map {
              x => x.title
            } getOrElse "nothing"

            complete("Done with " + doc)
          }

          case Failure(ex) => complete("error ${ex.getMessage}")
        }
      }
```

so I had the bright idea of writing the following function to encapsulate the work done to create a future out of a promise:

```
def callback2Future[T](funToCall: (T => Unit) => Any): Future[T] = {

    val p = Promise[T]
    val resultFuture = p future
    def callbacklistener(arg: T): Unit = {
      arg: T => p success arg
    }
    funToCall(callbacklistener)
    resultFuture
  }
```

And restructure the onComplete as:

```
 onComplete(OnCompleteFutureMagnet(callback2Future(archiveService.getByHash(ZeroHash, _: Option[DocumentRef] => Unit)))) {
          case Success(docRef) => {
...
}
```

In the original implementation with callservice, it works great (with great throughput too), with the `callback2Future` implementation I get a forever wait and it eventually times out. They seem the same to me, can anyone spot the error?

Comment: I doubt that `funToCall(callbacklistener)` is a partial application. So it returns a function and does not execute it. put `val a = ..` in front of this and debug to see what is the type of `a`

Comment: I forgot to say that I put a debug point in callback listener and it gets indeed called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is due to the infamous auto-Unit *feature* of Scala. Your function:

```
def callbacklistener(arg: T): Unit = {
  arg: T => p success arg
}
```

will probably be interpreted as:

```
def callbacklistener(arg: T): Unit = {
  { arg: T => p success arg }
  ()
}
```

What you really want is probably:

```
def callbacklistener(arg: T): Unit = p success arg
```

To be clear, in your implementation you are defining a function `callbackListener` with return type `Unit`; in the body of this function you have an expression, `{ arg: T => p success arg }`, whose value is of type `T => Unit` and is discarded; the Scala compiler will then put a free `()` in your code as the return type of the `callbackListener` is supposed to be `Unit`.